# exFAT Mounted HDD partition not mounting as specified user and instead as root

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, hard-drive, samba

Forgive me if this question has been asked before but I have tried to find an answer to no avail leading me to write this. Please link me the solution if this or something similar has been asked.

I have a Mac Mini running Ubuntu Server which is host to multiple Docker containers running various services for a home server. Each container has its own user which runs the container and is the owner of their own folders containing the service files. I have both a Jellyfin server and a Samba server which require read and write permissions for their respective folders.

For these servers to have space I have their running off of an external hard drive `/dev/sdb`, each with their own exFAT partition (for swapping between OSs). These partitions are mounted as `sudo mount -t exfat -o uid=115,gid=120 /dev/sdb2 /home/mini/Jellyfin/media` and the same concept applies to the Samba mount.
I do not apply these mounts on startup and I choose to mount them manually, so no changes have been made to `/etc/fstab`

User and group `115:120` corresponds to jellyfin's user account.
The output of `ls -l /home/mini/Jellyfin/`

```
total 144
drwxrwxr-x  6 jellyfin mini   4096 Jan  3 08:06 cache
drwxrwxr-x 12 jellyfin mini   4096 Jun 22  2023 config
-rw-rw-r--  1 jellyfin mini    607 Jan  7 11:35 docker-compose.yml
-rw-rw-r--  1 jellyfin mini    434 Jun 22  2023 docker-compose.yml.old
drwxr-xr-x  6 root     root 131072 Jan  8 07:35 media
```

I have attempted to run `sudo chown jellyfin /home/mini/Jellyfin/media` but receive `chown: changing ownership of '/home/mini/Jellyfin/media': Operation not permitted`.

I understand that exFAT doesn't have permissions built in which is why I try to mount the partitions as their respective users, but I don't understand why the mount point is mounted as root.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you're mounting the same sdb2 you think you are? What is sdb2 on one boot may not be the same on other boots. Run this command to verify: `sudo blkid -c /dev/null -o list`

Comment: Try with the unmounted partition, run:
sudo chmod -Rf 777 /home/mini/Jellyfin/media

Comment: An unmounted partition does not inherit the permissions of the mount point when the partition is mounted. This is true of all mounts.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, `sudo chmod -Rf 777 /home/mini/Jellyfin/media` worked, however I adjusted this to 664 for read and write for the owner and group members. That only worked when the drive was unmounted. When I checked 'ls -l /home/mini/Jellyfin/' after mounting, the ownership was correct, but the permissions appeared to allow for read, write, and execute access for everyone. This achieves the desired result (removing files directly from the web interface). Is this just a limitation of exFAT? Ideally I only want the jellyfin user (115:120) to have this access. Thank you!